# Python 3 import keras failure

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, keras

I installed python3, tensorflow and keras in a MacOS virtualenv environment, when I tried to import keras in python3, I got the following error:

```
Python 3.7.0 (default, Aug 22 2018, 15:22:33) 
[Clang 9.1.0 (clang-902.0.39.2)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import keras
Using TensorFlow backend.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from . import conv_utils
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
    from .. import backend as K
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/__init__.py", line 89, in <module>
    from .tensorflow_backend import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 114
    def TFE_ContextOptionsSetAsync(arg1, async):
                                             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade Python to 3.6 You get this error because `async` is now a keyword in Python 3.7